# What metrics are generated by @RefreshScope in Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana

Does using @RefreshScope annotation generates any metrics in springboot which can be visualised in grafana or prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have this enabled, the configuration refresh is automatically enabled via "/actuator/refresh" endpoint. This traffic should be automatically captured by prometheus. I dont have it setup locally, but query to get total count would be something like:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{method="GET",status="200",uri="/actuator/refresh",}
```

*update* adding official documentation from comment:

[Official Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR2/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#_endpoints)

Comment: I didnt really understand the comment and the link.

Comment: Did the query work and are you able to get metrics about that endpoint?

Comment: No, i am not getting metrics as i am not refreshing the config by calling the endpoint but instead programatically calling refresh

Comment: I see, in that case you will have to add a custom prometheus metric to track the calls/response time etc. That way it can be monitored.

Comment: yes i used custom prometheus metric eventually